# regular expression that can parse these example file paths

Tags: regex, parsing, expression

I need a regex that can parse the following example file paths and return the path, base, ext and num as shown in the following table.

This regex almost works, but unfortunately it falls short when the filename contains multiple periods.

```
^(.*\\)?(.*?)\.(.*?)\.?([0-9]+)?$

input                         path            base            ext     num
---------------------------   ------------    ----------      ------  ------
c:\temp\00883005.prt.1        c:\temp\        00883005        prt     1
00883005.prt                                  00883005        prt
00883005.prt.1                                00883005        prt     1
\\data\test\00883005.prt      \\data\test\    00883005        prt
\\data\test\00883005.prt.1    \\data\test\    00883005        prt     1
00883005.test.prt                             00883005.test   prt        
00883005.test.prt.1                           00883005.test   prt     1
c:\temp\00883005.test.prt.1   c:\temp\        00883005.test   prt     1
00883005.mp3                                  00883005        mp3
```

Here is the working AutoHotkey code (thanks to the folks below):

```
RegExMatch( filename, "^(.*\\)?(.*?)\.([^\.]*?)\.?(\b[0-9]+)?$", data)
outputdebug % "dir = " data1
outputdebug % "base = " data2
outputdebug % "ext = " data3
outputdebug % "num = " data4
```

Comment: What language are you doing this in? There might be a much better way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this version:

```
^(.*\\)?(.*?)\.([^\.]*?)\.?([0-9]+)?$
```

The difference is the second-to-last group: Changed `([^\.]*?)` to `(.*?)` such that dot is not included in the match.

Tested on the great [www.regexplanet.com](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html) against the provided data.

Comment: Excellent, but after reading mghicks response I added this example to the test 00883005.mp3 and this regex returns ext=mp and num=3.  It should return ext=mp3 and num=NULL?

Comment: Then just add `\b` before `[0-9]`

Comment: That seems to work well... THANKS to Jens Hoffmann, mghicks, and Tim Pietzcker.  This is the regex that works...   ^(.*\\)?(.*?)\.([^\.]*?)\.?(\b[0-9]+)?$

Answer (score 0):

seems like you can accommodate the multiple periods by simply adding on to the base name:

```
^(.*\\)?(.*?)\.((.*?)\.?)+([0-9]+)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee ext never includes numerals, then

`^(.*\\)?([^\\]+)\.([^.0-9]+)(?:\.([0-9]+))?`